# Programmatically create a UIViewController in a project with a storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a ViewController with "next" button that takes me to an instance of the same ViewController class.

```
@interface ViewControllerDeco ()
{
    ViewControllerDeco *page1;
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
page1 = [[ViewControllerDeco alloc]init];
```

button:

```
- (IBAction)btnNext:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:page1 animated:YES];
}
```

It shows me a black screen, am I missing something?

Comment: Is that view controller based on a storyboard? If so, you should load (instantiate) it from there and not just alloc/init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initiating view controller with

```
page1 = [[ViewControllerDeco alloc]init];
```

doesn't actually get it from storyboard, it just creates empty new one (which one you can set up in viewDidLoad for example), if you want to create that one from storyboard, you should do something like:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerDecoId"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

previously you should set "ViewControllerDecoId" to "Storyboard id" of your controller in your storyboard

hope helped

Answer (score 1):

So if you are not adding UI elements in your ViewControllerDeco controller init function, you will get a black screen. If you want to create an instance of ViewControllerDeco based on a view controller in your storyboard, try something like this:

```
ViewControllerDeco *page1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerDeco"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:page1 animated:YES];
```

Make sure to add a storyboard identifier to the VC that you want to load in code.